# Magento update product price

Tags: magento, onchange, product

I am trying to customize the magento associated product dropdown menu in frontend.
So far it's working good, But i need somehow to be able to update the price when a user has clicked the radio button. I guess i need to use some jquery stuff? The price is stored in the radio value. Any suggestions? :)

The code i'm currently working with is:

```
<?php
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
                $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
                $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
                foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ ?>

                    <input type="radio" id="attribute135" name="attribute135" value="<?php echo strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice())) ?>" /> <?php echo $simple_product->getName(); 
}
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended using:
$_product->setPrice(new price value here)

Comment: Unfortunately setPrice does not reflect in Magento's cart. Any ideas how to solve this?